# Why only one core is reported on Ubuntu VirtualBox(found when using std::async)?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I was playing with std::async() on my Ubuntu on VirtualBox. For some reason with std::asyc() for two tasks I was still not getting CPU usage more than 100%. I have mentioned std::launch:async flag for launching async tasks. 
I was expecting more than 100% usage as I have six core AMD ryzen 5. When I printed cpu info on ubuntu I get following

```
#include<iostream>
#include<random>
#include<set>
#include<algorithm>
#include<future>

std::set<int> unique_random(uint32_t numElem)
{
   std::set<int> retVal;
   std::random_device rd;
   std::mt19937 gen(rd());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, numElem-1);

   std::generate_n(std::inserter(retVal, retVal.end()), numElem, [&](){ return dist(gen);});

   return retVal;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "uniue random numbers in first run : " << std::async(std::launch::async, unique_random, 1000000).get().size() << '\n' <<"uniue random numbers in Second run : "<< std::async(std::launch::async, unique_random, 1000000).get().size() <<'\n';;

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation : g++ async_test.cpp -pthread -o3

time measure : /usr/bin/time ./a.out

```
#cat /proc/cpuinfo     
                                                                                                                         2552ms  Fri 29 May 2020 02:15:08 AM UTC
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 23
model       : 8
model name  : AMD Ryzen 5 2600X Six-Core Processor
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x6000626
cpu MHz     : 3593.248
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
***cpu cores    : 1***
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch ssbd vmmcall fsgsbase avx2 rdseed clflushopt arat
bugs        : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
bogomips    : 7186.49
TLB size    : 2560 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Here if you see it only reports 1 core. So I do know why I am not getting CPU usage more than 100% but why Ubuntu is showing only 1 core ?

Is it some bug with VirtualBox or am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Without code we cant really help you.  please add a [mre]

Comment: I have updated the question with minimal code example. I hope it will help.

Comment: Ah, I see now.  You've confused how `async` runs.  It doesn't run your code on all cores, it runs your code on it own single core (very over simplification).  If you want to use all cores, you need to launch a number of threads equal to that

Comment: I am not sure I get you so async will never use multiple cores?

Comment: Correct.  It runs the function you give it on it's own thread.  A thread can only run on a single core at a time.  If your CPU support 8 threads for instance, you would need to call `async` 8 times to consume all of the threads the CPU can run at one time.

Comment: I think calling get() immediately on async Will block it. Could that be affecting and make it run on single core ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I missed you were doing two calls like that.  I didn't scroll all the way over.  `get` will block as it has to yield a result.

Comment: Still one more question why cpuinfo showing up cpu cores as one ?

Comment: That I can't help with I'm afraid.  You might want to ask about it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)